# How can I get Explorer to restart when using Burn

Tags: wix, wix3.7, burn

In an msi, we use the following to get explorer to restart so that it loads our shell extension.

```
<util:RestartResource Path="[WindowsFolder]explorer.exe"/>
```

However, now that I've wrapped this msi up with its dependencies in an installer created with burn, the restart of Explorer no longer occurs.

How can I get the restart to still occur?

Thanks.

---

The msi normally displays some UI asking the user to reboot. This UI is hidden when wrapped in a burn/bundle exe. I thought perhaps the burn engine would issue callbacks allowing a custom bootstrapper to display the relevant UI. I tried overridding OnExecuteMsiMessage in a custom bootstrapper application, but don't see any message that would appear to give me an opportunity to display the UI that's required for the Explorer.exe restart.

Comment: The complete, original UI can be shown using [Wix/Bundle/Chain/MsiPackage/@DisplayInternalUI](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html) but maybe you don't want that.

Comment: Yep, I don't want the original UI... but you've given me an idea, I will see if it can handle restarting a process, and if it does will copy how it does it.